# Padrino Admin (12.0) + Mongoid: escaped quotes break MongoDB array syntax

Tags: mongoid, padrino, moped

Whenever I edit an object with an array field with Padrino Admin interface, the quotes are escaped and MongoDB doesn't recognize the array as an array anymore.

Fields are correctly defined as arrays in the object model definitions.

Any ideas?

Edit:
the array is received by the controller's post and put methods as such, it's after the document is persisted to MongoDB that it's escaped resulting in a string. Maybe this has to do with MongoDB serialization?

Comment: maybe you can at least explain what you are doing, what gets sent to mongodb and what mongodb receives (look in the logs, show example of what you see when you edit, and what ends up inserted). otherwise it's pretty hard to tell what exactly is breaking.

Comment: apologies for being side-tracked from this. i'll post the info + start another bounty in a few days. thanks for your interest.

Comment: Can you please provide some code samples with the results so we can properly replicate and help with the issue?